# Make effect nav

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

Is there any way to detect that div when scrolling, what I have in mind as the user goes down between the different sections of the page, my nav area go changing as be putting as activated the option that is at that time, such as: http: //www.blacktie.co/demo/munter/

I know this is a free platilla, but do not understand the code

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    delay(function() {

        var tops = [];

        $('.story').each(function(index, element) {
            tops.push( $(element).offset().top - 200 );
        });

        var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

        var lis = $('.nav > li');

        for ( var i=tops.length-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
            if ( scroll_top >= tops[i] ) {
                menu_focus( lis[i], i+1 );
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    pause);
});
```

this part of the code is most important.
this function is within the script.js file, it runs every time a user scrolls the website.

first it creates an Array with the name op tops,
next it goes trough the entire page and gets the offset from the top of each element containing the "story" class

for instance :

```
<!-- === Slide 2 === -->
    <div class="slide story" id="slide-2" data-slide="2">

or

<!-- === SLide 3 - Portfolio -->
<div class="slide story" id="slide-3" data-slide="3">
```

thereafter a variable in the name of "scroll_top" is created.
this variable holds the offset from the top of the current position

next, an array of list items is created with "`var lis = $('.nav > li');`"
then, there runs a for loop, checking each section of the web page (for which a list items is assigned).
it runs from bottom to top (i--).

if the scrollTop (current offset) is bigger or equal to the offset of the div with a class of "story", it means you are hovering above that one. there for, that's the list item that is supposed to be active, and so the "menu_focus()" will run.

Bellow the code of menu_focus.

```
function menu_focus( element, i ) {
    if ( $(element).hasClass('active') ) {
        if ( i == 6 ) {
            if ( $('.navbar').hasClass('inv') == false )
                return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    enable_arrows( i );

    if ( i == 1 || i == 6 )
        $('.navbar').removeClass('inv');
    else
        $('.navbar').addClass('inv');

    $('.nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(element).addClass('active');

    var icon = $(element).find('.icon');

    var left_pos = icon.offset().left - $('.nav').offset().left;
    var el_width = icon.width() + $(element).find('.text').width() + 10;

    $('.active-menu').stop(false, false).animate(
        {
            left: left_pos,
            width: el_width
        },
        1500,
        'easeInOutQuart'
    );
}
```

this function will first of all check if you are already on the same active menu, or if you are on the last menu item.
when this is true, it returns and the function will exit.

however, when this is false (and you need to change the current active menu item).
this is done by the code below :

```
$('.nav > li').removeClass('active');
$(element).addClass('active');
```

the active state is removed from all the list items, and then it is added to the current list item.

that last part off the code will check the length of the list item and creates a line according to it.
also, the `$('.active-menu').stop(false, false).animate(` part will animate the bar. that means it wont jump directly to the next but it will slide slowly (taking 1500 milliseconds.)

I hope this will help you in understanding the code. If not, ask me for futher explanation!

Greetings!